# Exception caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.reactivestreams.Publisher

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

In a JavaFX Gradle-based application that I develop using RxJava and Kotlin in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2 (Build #IC-171.4249.39), I'm getting an exception:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/reactivestreams/Publisher

everytime a code like this

```
return Completable.complete()
```

is executed. Following a suggestion of a similar question [Why I am getting NoClassDefFoundError: org/reactivestreams/Publisher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231477/why-i-am-getting-noclassdeffounderror-org-reactivestreams-publisher), I've tried to add include the reactive-streams to the `dependencies` block of my `build.gradle` script

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2'
    compile 'org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.0.0'
}
```

but the problem persists. The dependency tree looks like this one:

```
compile - Dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use 'implementation ' instead).
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2
|    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
\--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.0.0
     +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.7
     |    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.0 -> 1.1.2 (*)

compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2
|    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
\--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.0.0
     +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.7
     |    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.0 -> 1.1.2 (*)

+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2
|    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
\--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.0.0
     +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.7
     |    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.0 -> 1.1.2 (*)

\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing:1.1.2
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2
          \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0

kaptTest
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing:1.1.2
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2
          \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0

runtime - Runtime dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use 'runtimeOnly ' instead).
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2
|    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
\--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.0.0
     +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.7
     |    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.0 -> 1.1.2 (*)

runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2
|    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
\--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.0.0
     +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.7
     |    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.0 -> 1.1.2 (*)

testCompile - Dependencies for source set 'test' (deprecated, use 'testImplementation ' instead).
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2
|    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
\--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.0.0
     +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.7
     |    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.0 -> 1.1.2 (*)

testCompileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2
|    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
\--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.0.0
     +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.7
     |    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.0 -> 1.1.2 (*)

testRuntime - Runtime dependencies for source set 'test' (deprecated, use 'testRuntimeOnly ' instead).
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2
|    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
\--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.0.0
     +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.7
     |    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.0 -> 1.1.2 (*)

testRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'test'.
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2
|    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
\--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.0.0
     +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.7
     |    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.0 -> 1.1.2 (*)
```

As you can see, **org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams** is present in each environment.

Now, I've managed to resolve the problem by adding manually dependency on a [reactive-streams-1.0.0.jar](https://jar-download.com/?detail_search=g%3A%22io.reactivex.rxjava2%22&g=io.reactivex.rxjava2), but I don't like this solution at all.

Could somebody advice a better solution? Thanks!

Comment: why you are using rxjava2 kotlin and org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0 ?  io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.x.y... 
I think that you have to use io.reactivex:rxkotlin:1.x.y if you need to use  org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0 or pass to v2 version. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin